# Haskell: adding new datatypes used in overlapping instances, in a different module

Tags: haskell, types

Here is a problem I am bumping into in Haskell.

#### Background

I wish to be able to convert "things" which are datatypes to strings. The added complexity is that sometimes the resulting string might be different depending of a "Type" (which is also a datatype) being used. Moreover, I'd like users to be able to freely add their own "things" and "Types" in their own modules without modifying my own code. Last but not least, "things" can be nested, so one "thing" of type "A" can contain a "thing" of type "B".

#### Code

It'll hopefully be clearer with a bit of code and what I managed to do so far:

The following GHC extensions are being uses:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, OverlappingInstances #-}
```

Alright, first of all "Types" are defined with a datatype with two constructors:

- the default behavior ("DefaultType")
- a customized behavior ("MyTypeA").

```
data Types = DefaultType | MyTypeA
```

Then, a function "toString" is defined. It'll behave differently based on the constructor of the above type:

```
toString :: (MyTypeAString a, DefaultString a) => Types -> a -> String
toString DefaultType a = toDefaultString DefaultType a
toString MyTypeA a = toMyTypeAString a
```

Now, we have the two classes "MyTypeAString" and "DefaultString" to create. Let's start with the "DefaultString" one:

```
class DefaultString a where
    toDefaultString :: Types -> a -> String
```

"a" can be potentially anything to be converted to a string. Let's create two of those "things":

```
data TheThingA = TheThingA TheThingB
data TheThingB = TheThingB
```

Note that "TheThingB" is part of "TheThingA". You'll so see the consequence in the implementation of the instances of the DefaultString class:

```
instance DefaultString TheThingA where
    toDefaultString myType (TheThingA thingB) = "Thing A has " ++ toString myType thingB

instance DefaultString TheThingB where
    toDefaultString myType thing = "a thing B!"
```

The important point is the call to the "toString" function in the "TheThingA" instance. This call is the one which is the source of the problem I am running into as we'll see later.

Now, let's create the "MyTypeA" class:

```
class MyTypeAString a where
    toMyTypeAString :: (DefaultString a) => a -> String
```

The first instance is a general one (so the use of the "FlexibleInstances" GHC extension) which will act exactly as "toDefaultString" using "MyTypeA":

```
instance MyTypeAString a where
    toMyTypeAString thing = toDefaultString MyTypeA thing
```

The second instance is as so:

```
instance MyTypeAString TheThingB where
    toMyTypeAString thing = "a thing B created by MyTypeA"
```

That second instance is a specific implementation for the "TheThingB" for "MyTypeAsString". As this instance is overlapping the first one, we use the "OverlappingInstances".

Let's now run some tests to see how all this is behaving:

```
test1 = toString DefaultType (TheThingA TheThingB)
> "Thing A has a thing B!"

test2 = toString MyTypeA (TheThingA TheThingB)
> "Thing A has a thing B created by MyTypeA"
```

#### What is achieved so far

So, what is this all about? We've set a basic behavior for the "toString" function which will behave the same way regardless of the use "DefaultType" or "MyTypeA". You have now to imagine that we have not only "TheThingA" and "TheThingB" but a hundred of other data types with each one its own dedicated instance of the "DefaultString" class.
On the other hand, imagine that the class "MyTypeAString" behaves exactly the same way for 90% of those data types and have therefore very few specific instances. Using the "OverlappingInstances" we can save hundreds lines of code and have specific instances only for the cases "MyTypeAString" needs a different behavior, which is pretty neat.

#### The problem

So far, so good. But now, I'ld like to create a new "Type", which I want to call "MyTypeB"
This is nothing too complicated - I could just modify the datatype "Types" and the "toString" function type signature - but it is not very clean, in the sense that I would need to change the "Types" datatype itself and the "toString" function in the same module. What I would like to achieve is to let users define their own types and related classes in their own modules without modifying the "toString" function nor the "Types" datatype.
However, so far, I couldn't find a way to achieve this, so the question is **how to do this?**

Thanks a lot in advance for your help :-)

Comment: Holy long question batman! Adding a TLDR or shortening the question might help get answers :) Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: Removed some 100 lines, still holy long though... Thanks for the welcome :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is the solution with data type records, which is probably the most flexible:

```
data TheThingA = TheThingA TheThingB
data TheThingB = TheThingB

{-|
A data record type is created which holds the functions.
-}
data Stringable = Stringable {
      _toString  :: Stringable -> TheThingA -> String
    , _toStringB :: TheThingB -> String
}

{-|
The default function "toString" is implemented.
-}
toString :: Stringable -> TheThingA -> String
toString a (TheThingA thingB) = "Thing A has " ++ (_toStringB a) thingB

{-|
The default type is now a function which returns a Stringable with a specific
toStringB function.
-}
defaultType =
    Stringable toString toStringB
    where
        toStringB b = "a thing B!"

{-|
the myTypeA is the same as the defaultType but with a different toStringB
function.

Note: here we constructed the type from scratch. But using a library such as
Lens, we could re-use the defaultType and modify the only the records for which
we need another function.
-}
myTypeA =
    Stringable toString toStringB
    where
        toStringB b = "a thing B created by MyTypeA"
```

We can see running the tests that it brings the same results:

test1 = toString DefaultType (TheThingA TheThingB)

> "Thing A has a thing B!"

test2 = toString MyTypeA (TheThingA TheThingB)

> "Thing A has a thing B created by MyTypeA"

#### Comments

This is maybe a bit longer than the previous answer using type classes, but this is certainly a more flexible approach as it allows you to modify the behavior of a Stringable at any moment in the code using a library such as Lens.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question.

The idea is first to have "Types" as a type class instead of a data type, with an instance for "DefaultType" and one for "MyTypeA". Then, we can convert the function "toString" to a multi-param type class. Last but not least, the "DefaultString" type class becomes a multi-param one which enable to define type constraints on the head of its instances. Here is the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts
           , FlexibleInstances
           , MultiParamTypeClasses
           , OverlappingInstances
           , UndecidableInstances #-}

data DefaultType = DefaultType
data MyTypeA = MyTypeA

data TheThingA = TheThingA TheThingB
data TheThingB = TheThingB

{- |
    This type class only purpose is to be able to use it as constraint in type 
    signatures. It therefor implements only a dummy function.
-}
class Types a where
    -- | A dummy function.
    getName :: a -> String

instance Types DefaultType where
    getName a = "Default Type"

instance Types MyTypeA where
    getName a = "My Type A"

{- |
     The "toString" function is converted to a type class.
     The Types class is used to constraint type a.
-}
class Stringable a b where
    toString :: Types a => a -> b -> String

{- |
    Constraints are put in the instance head declaration. This way, one can add new Types
    such as MyTypeA, without modifying the toString type signature itself.
-}
instance (DefaultString MyTypeA b, MyTypeAString b) => Stringable MyTypeA b where
    toString a b = toMyTypeAString b

instance DefaultString DefaultType b => Stringable DefaultType b where
    toString = toDefaultString

class DefaultString a b where
    toDefaultString :: Types a => a -> b -> String

{- |
    Multiparam type class allows us to put a constraint on the second parameter of the
    function which is necessary due to the use of the toString function. 
-}
instance Stringable a TheThingB => DefaultString a TheThingA where
    toDefaultString myType (TheThingA thingB) =  "Thing A has " ++ toString myType thingB

instance DefaultString a TheThingB where
    toDefaultString myType thing = "a thing B!"

class MyTypeAString a where
    toMyTypeAString :: DefaultString MyTypeA a => a -> String

instance MyTypeAString a where
    toMyTypeAString thing = toDefaultString MyTypeA thing 

instance MyTypeAString TheThingB where
    toMyTypeAString thing = "a thing B created by MyTypeA"
```

We can run our tests:

```
test1 = toString DefaultType (TheThingA TheThingB)
> "Thing A has a thing B!"

test2 = toString MyTypeA (TheThingA TheThingB)
> "Thing A has a thing B created by MyTypeA"
```

#### Going further

Now it is possible to have a new type such as "MyType" created as a new instance of "Types". We can define customized behaviors for this new type by creating a new class such as "MyTypeBString" as we did it for "MyTypeAString". All this can be done in a separated module, which provides us with a lot of flexibility.

Should you find a better answer (for example, not relying on so many GHCI extensions, or with simpler type signatures) please do not hesitate to post it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I answer again my own question with a better solution which does not require any extensions and much shorter!

```
data DefaultType = DefaultType
data MyTypeA = MyTypeA

data TheThingA = TheThingA TheThingB
data TheThingB = TheThingB

{-|
We define in a type class a specific toString functions for each data type
(TheThingA and TheThingB). The one for TheThingA is our "toString" function.

On top of that, a default implementation is added.
-}    
class Stringable a where
    toString :: a -> TheThingA -> String
    toString a (TheThingA thingB) = "Thing A has " ++ toStringB a thingB

    toStringB :: a -> TheThingB -> String
    toStringB a thing = "a thing B!"

{-|
Since the default implementation covers the behavior for the DefaultType,
there is no need to specify any functions for this instance.
-}
instance Stringable DefaultType where

{-|
For the MyTypeA class, only the toStringB function needs to be defined.
-}    
instance Stringable MyTypeA where
    toStringB a thing = "a thing B created by MyTypeA"
```

We can run our tests:

```
test1 = toString DefaultType (TheThingA TheThingB)
> "Thing A has a thing B!"

test2 = toString MyTypeA (TheThingA TheThingB)
> "Thing A has a thing B created by MyTypeA"
```

#### Going further

It seems there might be even more elegant solutions using record data types. I will try to provide such a one as well.